# OnTouch not Firing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android and I am trying to hide an image, but it seems the OnTouch is not being fired, can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {    
/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
//GameView theView;
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //theView = new GameView(this);
    //theView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.myviewlay);
    setContentView(R.layout.myviewlay);

  }
public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event)
{

         ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView03);
         image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         view.invalidate();  
         return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override OnTouchEvent fixes your issue.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int action = event.getAction();
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView03);
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: Wow this worked great! one last question.. is there any way to identify if Imageview03 is being clicked and not ImageView02?,because if i can do this then i can do a switch statement.. I am just not sure how to with android...

Comment: ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Image01);
   imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // do your event here.
    }
   });

Answer (score 0):

Setting event listener on ImageView enables you to find the image you touched.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image01);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do your event here.
                }
            });

            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is awesome Howard, thank you so much!. Can I give you more points :), I have another question but i might be being bad by asking so many questions.. In Java I can do a Thread.sleep(1000), if i want it so delay the program... When they click the image, can I do a Thread.Sleep(1000) just so that it takes a little while while the OnTouch?

Comment: Sure you can, just remind that use try catch to surround the Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: When I try it, it would make the screen black :(

Comment: Use eclipse->window->show view->logcat to see if there is any exception. I tried and it works fine.

Comment: Yes this worked, I had the thread in the wrong place :) Thank you so much